# Angular UI Select UI Scroll (Infinite scroll on select box)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I have a Java backend API which provides me paged results. For typical, data list view, I use infinite-scroll. But, how do I use this out-of-the-box with a Select Box.

I digged out this PR, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/620, but have no clue how to go about using it. Also, the same author in his last post mentioned that it is still buggy.

If there is no ready solution, the next best solution seems to be this - using a button inside a select box and hitting "Load More.." which is kind of hacky:
https://jsfiddle.net/betonetotbo/0yfhe7pf/

```
        <ui-select ng-model="data.selected" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Type 'a' to display results...">
          {{$select.selected.full_name}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices 
          refresh="fetch($select)" 
          refresh-delay="300" 
          repeat="item in items | filter: $select.search"
        >       
          {{$index}} - {{item.full_name}}
          <div ng-if="$index == $select.items.length-1">
            <button 
              ng-if="!useNgMouseover" 
              class="btn btn-xs btn-success" 
              style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;" 
              ng-click="fetch($select, $event);"
              ng-disabled="loading">Load more...</button>                 

          </div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

Am pretty sure somebody out there has already implemented it. Any clues?